# Why do the fadeIn and animate not happen at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Why does the animate wait for the fadeIn to complete before it executes, can anyone shed some light for me please?

```
//Price Navigation FadeIn

$('#header-base > ul').hide().css({'top':'50px'});

$('#header-base > ul').fadeIn(500);
$('#header-base > ul').animate({'top':'0px'});
```

I want the fadeIn and animate to happen simultaneously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that animations are automatically put in the effects queue.  You can alter this by supplying a `queue` setting:

```
$('#header-base > ul').animate({top: '0px'}, {queue: false});
```

See the [`animate` API](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why they don't happen at the same time, but a quick fix is to just

1. Set the element's opacity to 0
2. Show the element
3. Add an opacity fade-in to your animate function...

Perhaps something like...

```
$('#header-base > ul').css({'top':'50px', 'opacity':'0'});
$('#header-base > ul').animate({top:'0px', opacity: 100}, 500);
```

Comment: but wont that have issues in older browsers that don't support opacity, in particular ie?

Comment: @jai i suppose it might yes. I believe lonesomeday's found the real problem though.